# Fetch tagged people using Instagram sdk in iOS application

Tags: ios, objective-c, instagram, instagram-api

I have integrated Instagram SDK in my iPhone application. I want to fetch people tagged in media. I know I've to make a simple API call to get data which I mentioned below.

https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/{tag-name}?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN

I'm not sure what is tag_name here. What should I include in place of tag_name?

Comment: The `tags` endpoint is used to fetch pictures with specific hashtags.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [Media Endpoint](https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/media/#get_media) of the Instagram API: `GET /media/media-id`

The people tagged in the photo/video will appear in `users_in_photo` in the JSON response.

Comment: Thanks for answer Pieter.

Comment: Don't forget to accept it as an answer if it helped.

Comment: I already tried but I don't have enough reputation to accept it.

Comment: You should have enough now.

Comment: Thanks for accepting question. I will accept it once I will get enough reputation.